# Uninitialized fields inside an Object

Tags: scala, initialization, lazy-evaluation

I am currently fixing a very odd error where a `private final val` inside an object fields aren't initialised before they are accessed. The location of the code can be found at https://github.com/mdedetrich/soda-time/blob/master/jvm/src/main/scala/org/joda/time/chrono/GregorianChronology.scala#L12-L33.

You can simulate this error by pulling the above repo and then running `sodatimeJVM/console` and then in console running ` import org.joda.time._;  DateTime.now().minusDays(10)

The code has been posted here

```
object GregorianChronology {

  private final val MILLIS_PER_YEAR = (365.2425 * DateTimeConstants.MILLIS_PER_DAY).toLong
  private final val MILLIS_PER_MONTH = (365.2425 * DateTimeConstants.MILLIS_PER_DAY / 12).toLong
  private final val DAYS_0000_TO_1970 = 719527
  private final val MIN_YEAR = -292275054
  private final val MAX_YEAR = 292278993
  private final val INSTANCE_UTC = getInstance(DateTimeZone.UTC)

  private final val cCache = new ConcurrentHashMap[DateTimeZone, Array[GregorianChronology]]()

  def getInstanceUTC(): GregorianChronology = INSTANCE_UTC

  def getInstance(): GregorianChronology = getInstance(DateTimeZone.getDefault, 4)

  def getInstance(zone: DateTimeZone): GregorianChronology = getInstance(zone, 4)

  def getInstance(zone: DateTimeZone, minDaysInFirstWeek: Int): GregorianChronology = {
    var _zone: DateTimeZone = zone
    if (_zone == null) {
      _zone = DateTimeZone.getDefault
    }
    var chrono: GregorianChronology = null
    var chronos: Array[GregorianChronology] = cCache.get(_zone)
```

The last line, i.e. `var chronos: Array[GregorianChronology] = cCache.get(_zone)` throws a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. The value that is null is `cCache` however this doesn't make sense since its clearly being initialized at `private final val cCache = new ConcurrentHashMap[DateTimeZone, Array[GregorianChronology]]()`. If I turn on `"-Xcheckinit"` Scala then tells me `scala.UninitializedFieldError: Uninitialized field: GregorianChronology.scala: 19` which points to `private final val cCache = new ConcurrentHashMap[DateTimeZone, Array[GregorianChronology]]()`. This isn't very useful as I know that the value isn't initialized, the problem is that I don't know **why**. Since its a final val I assume it should be one of the first values that are initialized, especially before `getInstance` ever happens to be called.

I know that I can make the value lazy to fix it, that would however introduce an unneeded performance hit. More importantly though, the equivalent Java version `private static final ConcurrentHashMap<DateTimeZone, GregorianChronology[]> cCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<DateTimeZone, GregorianChronology[]>()` works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
private final val INSTANCE_UTC = getInstance(DateTimeZone.UTC)
```

It calls:

```
def getInstance(zone: DateTimeZone): GregorianChronology = getInstance(zone, 4)
```

Which calls:

```
def getInstance(zone: DateTimeZone, minDaysInFirstWeek: Int): GregorianChronology = {
  ..
  var chronos: Array[GregorianChronology] = cCache.get(_zone)
  ..
}
```

But `INSTANCE_UTC` is still being initialized, which means we haven't reached `cCache` in the initialization order, so `cCache` is `null` at that point at run time.

This is similar to:

```
object Test {
    val a = foo("a") // Calls a def which references and uses an uninitialized val, NPE
    val b = "b"
    def foo(c: String): Int = b.length + c.length
}
```

The solution is simple though, just move the initialization of `cCache` to the top of the object, since it doesn't reference anything else. That way it will always be initialized first.